# How can I grep a specific file in a specific revision (unchanged in that revision) in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have several repositories that I am building a tool to interact with.  I have not been able to find a way to grep a specific file in a specific revision that was unchanged in that revision.

The help for `hg grep` says that the `-r` option `-r --rev REV [+]         only search files changed within revision range`.  If I update the revision in question, I can grep appropriately, and I get the desired results.  Because my file in question is unchanged in that revision, it will not get grepped.  Does anyone know a way to do this?

My end goal is that I would like to ignore files that meet a certain pattern matching.  I am not sure that using the `--all` option would be feasible, because I would have to parse the revisions that the pattern appeared and disappeared in.

Thanks in advance.

**edit:**
Actual problem I'm trying to solve:

There are several tagged revisions in a repository.

For each of those tagged revisions, I would like to extract a particular file (assume `source/a.c` or something like that) to a folder structure that others can access (a website for those outside of our group, whom we cannot give repository access to).

But, I would only like to extract the file if it does not contain a particular pattern.  This is why I would like to check the file at a specific revision, even if it has been unchanged.

Comment: What is the actual problem you try to solve? What exactly do you mean with 'grep for a file in a revision where it was unchanged'? You want to look inside the files or only look for filenames matching your pattern?

Comment: @planetmaker edited the original post to be more specific about the actual problem.

I would like to search the contents of that file for a particular piece of text.  The file may or may not have been changed from the parent revision.

Answer (score 0):

Right, `hg grep` indeed does not analyse the file contents at a particular revision but only when the file actually changes. Thus I suggest a slightly different way:

Get the revisions to check as a nice list:

```
hg log -r"tag()" --template="{rev}\n"
```

Using it this way (instead of tags) allows to also look at revisions which are not tagged. If it's really only tags, you might resort to the hg tags command directly: `hg tags --template="{tag}\n". It would make the $i in the small script below a nice tag name instead of a revision :)

You can use this list to get the file FILENAME at those respective revisions and then you need some small script which actually checks that file for the content in question:

```
for i in $(hg log -r"tag()" --template="{rev}\n"); do
  if hg cat FILENAME -r$i 2>/dev/null | grep PATTERN > /dev/null; then 
    hg cat FILENAME -r$i > path/to/whereever/FILENAME.$i
  fi
done
```

Comment: You may want to use `hg cat` instead of `hg revert` as a non-destructive way of getting at the contents of a file.

Comment: Yep, this is functionally what I ended up doing (I'm on windows, tool in C#).  It's a little disappointing though that this functionality is missing from Mercurial.  Also, I believe your script would copy the file contents of the revision currently updated to instead of the file contents at the particular revision.  It ends up being two calls to `hg cat`.

Comment: also yes to that. It was correct with the revert, but I overlooked this when changing the first line to using cat